# How use async return value from useEffect as default value in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a simple example https://codesandbox.io/s/4zq852m7j0.

As you can see I'm fetching some data from a remote source. I'd like to use the return value as the value inside my textfield.

```
const useFetch = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(
    async () => {
      const response = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar");
      const data = await response.json();
      setValue(data.args.foo);
    },
    [value]
  );

  return value;
};
```

However using the value inside the `useState` function does not work. I think `useState` uses the default value only on first render. When first rendering the value is obviously not set since it's async. The textfield should have the value `bar` but it is empty.

```
function App() {
  const remoteName = useFetch();
  // i want to see the remote value inside my textfield
  const [name, setName] = useState(remoteName);

  const onChange = event => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>remote name: {remoteName}</p>
      <p>local name: {name}</p>
      <input onChange={onChange} value={name} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

After fetching the value from remote I'd like to be able to change it locally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that `useFetch` returns a value that is available asynchronously, what you need is to update localState when the remoteValue is available, for that you can write an effect

```
const remoteName = useFetch();
  // i want to see the remote value inside my textfield
  const [name, setName] = useState(remoteName);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      console.log("inside effect");
      setName(remoteName);
    },
    [remoteName] // run when remoteName changes
  );

  const onChange = event => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymjq6qz9qx)**

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly same case as setting initial state asynchronously in class component:

```
state = {};

async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch(...);
  ...
  this.setState(...);
}
```

Asynchronously retrieved state cannot be available during initial render. Function component should use same technique as class component, i.e. conditionally render children that depend on a state:

```
  return name && <div className="App">...</div>;
```

This way there's no reason for `useFetch` to have its own state, it can maintain common state with the component (an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o78027j8nz)):

```
const useFetch = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(
    async () => {
      const response = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar");
      const data = await response.json();
      setValue(data.args.foo);
    },
    [] // executed on component mount
  );

  return [value, setValue];
};

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useFetch();

  const onChange = event => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  return name && (
    <div className="App">
      <p>local name: {name}</p>
      <input onChange={onChange} value={name} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When `bar` is an empty string (remove the value inside the text field) the whole component is gone.

Comment: If using empty string as initial state doesn't serve your purpose, don't use it. You can use `useState()` and do `name != null && ...` check instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not possible to pass the initial state as an async function?

i.e

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState(async () => fetch("https://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar").json().args.foo);
```