# Initializing the value of a state using a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

So essentially for every "post" component, I want to go to the database and check if my user has liked the post or not. So to do this, I am doing the following. Note liked is a state which checks if the like button is "pressed" or not.

```
const getLike = ()=>{
        if(!props.item.item){
            const a = db().collection("posts").doc(props.item.id).collection("likes").doc(props.myInfo.uid).get()
            .then((data)=>{
                if(data){
                       return true
                }
             })
            }
    return false
}


const [liked, setLiked] = useState(getLike())
```

The problem with this is for some reason it always returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298626/how-use-async-return-value-from-useeffect-as-default-value-in-usestate

Answer (score 0):

It's because the if part in `getLike` is invoking a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and returning the true in the `then` chainable.

You should change your code as follows:

```
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);

const getLike = ()=>{
        if(!props.item.item){
            const a = db().collection("posts").doc(props.item.id).collection("likes").doc(props.myInfo.uid).get()
            .then((data)=>{
                if(data){
                       setLiked(true) // we call our setLiked after the promise has resolved.
                }
             })
            }
}

useEffect(() => getLike(), []) // we want to call getLike() only once after the component has mounted.
```

Comment: My problem with using this, is that I am also using a custom hook basically component did update, where the first initialization of the liked state is ignored, but after that the hook lets me know that the liked state was updated, so that I can rewrite the state of the like to the database. Now the code above will initialize liked twice once when setting it to false, and second time when setting it to whatever the database says it is. so how can I make it so it only intializes once with the correct value

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using `Promise` i.e., `db().collection("posts")....` is asynchronous so `.then` will be called only when the response is received from the server. But it'll not stop executing the next lines in the code i.e.,  `return false`.
So after `db().collection("posts")....` call made, then the next line will also get executed. Which is why `false` is been returned always.

Below provided an examples of simulating `Promises`

```js
const promiseFn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Resolved")
    }, 1000)
  })
}

const promiseFnCall1 = () => {
  promiseFn().
  then(res => console.log(res))
  
  //This will be executed before `promiseFn` returns the response
  console.log("This is executed first");
}

promiseFnCall1();


//If there's some operation that needs to be performed only
//after the success response from a Promise that should be
//done in .then method
const promiseFnCall2 = () => {
  promiseFn().
  then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log("This is the correct order of execution");
  }) 
}

promiseFnCall2();
```

Also it is not recommended to call a promise in order to initialise state using `useState` instead you can initialise the state with default value as `false` and use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to get the data from backend and update it accordingly.

```js
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!props.item.item) {
    const a = db().collection("posts").doc(props.item.id).collection("likes").doc(props.myInfo.uid).get()
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          setLiked(true)
        }
      })
  }
}, [])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem with using this, is that I am also using a custom hook basically component did update, where the first initialization of the liked state is ignored, but after that the hook lets me know that the liked state was updated, so that I can rewrite the state of the like to the database. Now the code above will initialize liked twice once when setting it to false, and second time when setting it to whatever the database says it is. so how can I make it so it only intializes once with the correct value

Comment: Make this db call in the parent component and send it as props, so that it can be initialised only once in this component.

Comment: This doesnt work either. Because in the child component, you need to have another useEffect that waits for the props to update, so once again it reinitailizes twice.